# Batch script to zip the log files and move to archive folder

Tags: batch-file

I have a requirement to zip the logs file which is a week older and move the zip file to the archive folder.

I have used below command to zip the files, but need a help in identifying the files which is a week older. This process will be scheduled to run weekly once on Monday. So the command should zip the files from previous Monday to Sunday.

```
@echo off

set "srcFolder=D:\Data\Logs\*.log"
set "archFile=ETLDataLogs.zip"

tar.exe acvf "%archFile%" "%srcFolder%"
```

NOTE: There is no third party zip tools available in the server.

Comment: I recommend reading the [GNU tar manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/) if `%SystemRoot%\System32\tar.exe` is the tool you want to use for the file archiving task into a ZIP compressed archive file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have tar on your system you can use it: For example: `tar -cvf my_files.tar /path/to/my/directory`

For old files you could use the --delete option [tar delete option](https://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/delete.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20remove%20members%20from,names%2C%20nothing%20will%20be%20deleted.) and you hang the date to the my_files_2023-09-25.tar This way you could filter out the old ones. There are many more options and I think you will your anwser using google.